# Python Extracting multiple URLs from a table

Tags: python

I am currently working on a scrapping project in Python where I would like to extract the names and URLs from a list, however, the names are in the same tr and do not have any separators, as shown below. How can I extract these values in python?
[image]

The most relevant HTML code looks like this

```
<tr>
                            <th>Children:</th>
                            <td>
                                    <a href="https://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?dbid=60525&amp;h=24063369&amp;indiv=try&amp;viewrecord=1&amp;r=an" title="View record" class="contentLink" data-tracking-event="content : content link clicked">Myrna Jean Aune</a>
                                    <a href="https://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?dbid=60525&amp;h=154795469&amp;indiv=try&amp;viewrecord=1&amp;r=an" title="View record" class="contentLink" data-tracking-event="content : content link clicked">Robert Lee Aune</a>
                                    <a href="https://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?dbid=60525&amp;h=162126224&amp;indiv=try&amp;viewrecord=1&amp;r=an" title="View record" class="contentLink" data-tracking-event="content : content link clicked">Andrew Conrad Aune</a>
                                    <a href="https://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?dbid=60525&amp;h=201352962&amp;indiv=try&amp;viewrecord=1&amp;r=an" title="View record" class="contentLink" data-tracking-event="content : content link clicked">Arlene M. Olson</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to consider to use an HTML parser, like this:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
parser = MyHTMLParser()
tags = parser.feed('<a>')
urls = []
for tag_name, value in tags.items():
     if tag_name == 'src':
           urls.append(value)
```

In urls you will have all the link :)